# Why does this regex not work: r'.*logo.*'

Tags: python, regex, string

I expect the following regular expression to match, but it does not. Why?

```
import re
html = '''
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%">
                    </img>
                 </a>
  '''
m = re.match( r'.*logo.*', html, re.M|re.I)

if m: 
    print m.group(1)
if not m:
    print "not found"
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't use regex to parse HTML.

REPEAT AFTER ME: WE DON'T USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML.

That said, it doesn't work because `re.match` explicitly only checks the beginning of the line. Use `re.search` or `re.findall` instead.

Comment: *Recommends beautiful soup.*

Comment: This answer is better than mine because it gets to the root of the problem.

Comment: (quickest way to get reputation on SO? Telling someone not to use regex to parse HTML.)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, Beautiful Soup is just a wrapper around lxml.html these days; why not use the real, underlying library (which is arguably a bit better-designed) directly?

Comment: ...but, err, shouldn't the use of a leading `.*` and `re.MULTILINE` allow `re.match` to work too, since the `.*` should match all the preceding content, even through linebreaks?

Comment: (though admittedly, arguing about how to do an evil thing better is kinda' silly, as opposed to holding a hard line on Don't Do That).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy from the docs: "Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line."

Comment: Ahh, gotcha -- `re.DOTALL` would be necessary for the leading `.*` to match newlines. Now that makes sense.

Comment: @adsmith As much as I agree with not parsing HTML with regex, giving the OP an example using a parsing library would help correct him of his erred ways.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search`. `re.match` assumes the match is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: ...well, arguably, the `.*` should allow this to match anyhow, with `re.MULTILINE` in use.

Comment: Ok, so if that's not the problem, what is?

Comment: That's a good question, and if I knew (or, well, had time/inclination to reproduce), I'd be posting an answer myself. :)

Comment: Answered -- would need `re.DOTALL` in addition to `re.MULTILINE` for the leading `.*` to match past a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to include the re.DOTALL (== re.S) flag to allow the . to match newline (\n).

However, that returns the *entire document* if "logo" appears anywhere in it; not terribly useful.

Slightly better is

```
import re
html = """
    <a href="#">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%" />
    </a>
"""

match_logo = re.compile(r'<[^<]*logo[^>]*>', flags = re.I | re.S)

for found in match_logo.findall(html):
    print(found)
```

which returns

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%" />
```

Better yet would be

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pg = BeautifulSoup(html)
print pg.find("img", {"alt":"logo"})
```